# PHP call Class method / function

Tags: php, class, function, methods

How can I call following Class method or function?

Let say I have this params get from url:

```
$var = filter($_GET['params']);
```

**Class:**

```
class Functions{

    public function filter($data){
        $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));

        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
            $data = stripslashes($data);

        $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);

        return $data;
    }

}
```

thanks.

Comment: an aside to your question, if your `Functions::filter()` is code that you intend to use, please be aware that the php mysql_* extension has been deprecated. Use mysqli_* or pdo_* and strongly consider using prepared statements (which will remove the need for your function anyway).

Comment: Don't randomly "filter" data. You're just mangling your data completely out of shape. Learn what you're trying to do here first: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To answer your question, the current method would be to create the object then call the method:

```
$functions = new Functions();
$var = $functions->filter($_GET['params']);
```

Another way would be to make the method `static` since the class has no private data to rely on:

```
public static function filter($data){
```

This can then be called like so:

```
$var = Functions::filter($_GET['params']);
```

Lastly, you do not need a class and can just have a file of functions which you include. So you remove the `class Functions` and the `public` in the method. This can then be called like you tried:

```
$var = filter($_GET['params']);
```

Answer (score 5):

Within the class you can call function by using :

```
 $this->filter();
```

Outside of the class

you have to create an object of a class

```
 ex: $obj = new Functions();

     $obj->filter($param);
```

for more [about OOPs](http://php.net/oop) in php

**this** example:

```
class test {
 public function newTest(){
      $this->bigTest();// we don't need to create an object we can call simply using $this
      $this->smallTest();
 }

 private function bigTest(){
      //Big Test Here
 }

 private function smallTest(){
      //Small Test Here
 }

 public function scoreTest(){
      //Scoring code here;
 }
}

$testObject = new test();

$testObject->newTest();

$testObject->scoreTest();
```

hope it will help!

Comment: Sandip, without an instance he can not refer it within the class with $this too.

Answer (score 2):

Create object for the class and call, if you want to call it from other pages.

```
$obj = new Functions();

$var = $obj->filter($_GET['params']);
```

Or inside the same class instances [ methods ], try this.

```
$var = $this->filter($_GET['params']);
```

Comment: small quibble, usage of `$this` must be within the object, not within the page.

Comment: @dnagirl Small(er) quibble: usage of `$this` must be within instance methods of the object, not just anywhere in the object (i.e. not statics and not outside of a method body)

Comment: @ColinMorelli: miniscule quibble: that's why I said "object" and not "class". ;)  But clarity is good and you're entirely correct.

Comment: @dnagirl Not a quibble at all: Touche. but I have still seen people try the whole: `private $property = $this->getPropertyValue()` declaration at the top of their class and wonder why it doesn't work :). In any case - I really just felt like pointing out something even smaller than you pointed out...for fun.

Answer (score 1):

```
$f = new Functions;
$var = $f->filter($_GET['params']);
```

Have a look at the PHP manual section on [Object Oriented programming](http://php.net/oop)

Answer (score 1):

As th function is not using `$this` at all, you can add a `static` keyword just after public and then call

```
Functions::filter($_GET['params']);
```

Avoiding the creation of an object just for one method call

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `Object` for the `class.`

```
$obj = new Functions();
$var = $obj->filter($_GET['params']);
```

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
 $instance = new Functions(); // create an instance (object) of functions class
 $instance->filter($data); // now call it
```