# Error: Call to undefined function in Command line code on line 1

Tags: php, command-line

i am using my command line to excute a method within a class. however i keep getting the following message:

```
Error: Call to undefined function test() in Command line code on line 1
```

**this is my class and method:**

```
class DatasetTest
{
   public function test()
    {
       echo ""worked";
   }

}
```

this is my command line order:

```
$ php -r 'require "DatasetTest.php"; test();'
```

i also tried:

```
$ php -r 'require "DatasetTest.php"; $this->test();'
```

but got following message;

```
Error: Using $this when not in object context in Command line code on line 1
```

Comment: `echo ""worked` - extra quote

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499513/php-call-class-method-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute a method without instantiate the object, unless you define it as static.

**Solution #1**

```
class DatasetTest
{
   public static function test()
   {
       echo "worked";
   }

}
```

There is also a mistake that i've corrected with double quotes. Then you can execute

```
$ php -r 'require "DatasetTest.php"; DatasetTest::test();'
```

**Solution #2**

```
function test()
{
    echo "worked";
}
```

Then

```
$ php -r 'require "DatasetTest.php"; test();'
```